# Inserting exclusion on find command line

Tags: bash

I have run into an interesting problem.

I have a application that finds specific content. It will take content from its
command line as a list of exclusions. Here is a quick code hack to demonstrate the issue:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

gen.exclude () {

    local i

    for i in "$@" ; do
        echo -n "-not -path *${i}* "
    done
}

run.find () {
    echo find . $(gen.exclude "$@") -print
    find . $(gen.exclude "$@") -print
}

rm -rf a
rm -rf b
mkdir a
mkdir b

echo "file 1a" >a/file1
echo "file 2a" >a/file2
echo "file 3a" >a/file3
echo "file 1b" >b/file1
echo "file 2b" >b/file2
echo "file 3b" >b/file3

cp -r "a" "b/a"

run.find '/a/'      # fails because of wild card expansion
```

In this example, an exclude is created for */a/* to -not -path */a/*. Unfortunately, this then gets wild card expanded into multiple strings and causes find to error out.

I could surround the excluded in quotes, but then they get seen as part of the exclusion string which makes it a noop.

Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: Please add the result of `echo find . $(gen.exclude "$@") -print` so we can see what the find command looks like before you execute it.

Comment: This isn't a safe way to generate a command line. Use an array instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't separate `gen.exlude` from `run.exclude`; build an array of inclusions inside `run.exclude`.

```
run.exclude () {
    local -a exclusions
    for i in "$@"; do
        exclusions+=( -not -path "*$i*" )
    done
    echo "find . ${exclusions[*]} -print"
    find . "${exclusions[@]}" -print
}
```

For some arguments, what you log won't look identical to what you actually run, but what you run will be *correct*.

Comment: I honestly didn't think of using an array. Not a bad solution. Will try it in my environment.